# product of an ideal in K with its conjugate ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{d})}$ , d squarefree and $\mathbb{a}$ an ideal in $\mathcal O_k$ . I have to show that $$\mathbb{a}\mathbb{\overline a}=N(\mathbb{a})\mathcal O_k $$ where N denotes the norm .

First approach :
Since both sides are multiplicative on ideals , it suffices to show the equation for a prime ideal  $\mathbb{a}=\mathbb{p}$ .

1.)If $N(\mathbb{p})=p^2$ , for p prime  , then it follows $$ (N(p))=(p^2)=p\mathcal O_k p\mathcal O_k=p\mathcal O_k \overline p \overline {\mathcal   O_k}=\mathbb{p}\mathbb{\overline p}. $$

2) If $N(\mathbb{p})=p$ then $p\mathcal O_k=\mathbb{p}^2$ and $$(p)=\mathbb{p}^2=\mathbb{p}\mathbb{\overline p}. $$

Thanks for the help .

Comment: " If $N(\mathbb{p})=p$ then $p\mathcal O_k=\mathbb{p}^2$ " doesn't make any sense. In quadratic field $O_K = \Bbb{Z}[\tau]= \Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+ax+b)$ and depending on the factorization of $x^2+ax+b\bmod p$ there are 3 cases $(p) = (p,\tau-n)(p,\overline{\tau}-n)$ (two distinct prime ideals of norm $p$) or $ (p)$  prime or $(p) = (p,\tau-n)^2=(p,\tau-n)(p,\overline{\tau}-n)$.

Comment: What is your definition for $N(\mathbb{a})$?

Comment: $N(\mathbb{a})$=$|\mathcal O_k:\mathbb{a}|$

Comment: or could I also take the norm on both sides and use that $N(\mathbb{a})=N(\mathbb{\overline a})$ ?